# find missing values between two tables

Tags: compare, exists, not-exists

I have two tables named selected_courses and all_courses. I want to find not selected courses with sql queries.
Tables:

```
selected_course               all_courses
+---------------+            +------------+
student_id|course_id          course_id|course_name
+---------------+            +------------+
1             A1                A1
1             A2                A2
1             A3                A3 
2             A2                A4
2             A3
```

select all_courses.* from all_courses where not exists (select course_id from selected_courses where student_id='1')

this query returns nothing

select all_courses.* from all_courses left join selected_courses on selected_courses.course_id =all_courses.course id

in this query i cant apply where student_id='1' condition.

how can apply this condtion or use not exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out using not exists

```
select all_courses.courses_id from all_courses where not exists (select selected_courses.course_id from taken_courses where selected.course_id=all_courses.course_id and selected_courses.student_id='1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a left join and then excluding all entries that have a null

```
SELECT all_courses.*, sc.student_id
FROM all_courses AS ac
LEFT JOIN selected_courses AS sc ON (sc.course_id = al.course id)
WHERE sc.student_id IS NULL
```

Comment: it returns nothing.If i change to is not null it gives me selected courses by student.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? MySQL, MariaDB, MSSQL?

Comment: Im using MSSQL .I figured out using not exists 
select all_courses.courses_id from all_courses where  not exists (select selected_courses.course_id from taken_courses where selected.course_id=all_courses.course_id and selected_courses.student_id='1')

Comment: OK, add that as an answer and select it as the correct on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for specific student, do the following:

```
SELECT a.course_id, a.course_name
FROM all_courses a
LEFT JOIN selected_courses s ON a.course_id = s.course id AND s.student_id  = 1
WHERE s.student_id IS NULL
```